# Foreach con muchos problemas de tiempo me tira un gateway 504

Tags: php, laravel

Paso a mostrar mi codigo donde creo usuarios atraves de un excel en donde el foreach me esta consumiendo muchos datos me gustaria saber una mejor forma de resolverlo, ya que en el foreach le creo claves de firma a los usuarios,aparte de un codigo para que ingresen y cambien la contrasenia y la auditoria solo es un dato que se guarda por usuario, si me pueden aconsejar para mejorar mi arquitectura de codigo seria ideal. gracias

```
public function import(Request $request){
            
             $headings = (new HeadingRowImport)->toArray(request()->file('file'));
             $import = new CMusuariosImport($headings[0][0]);
             $array = ( $import )->toArray(request()->file('file'));
             $errores_lista = array();
             foreach($array[0] as $item){

                $errores = array();

                if(User::where('email',$item['correo'])->count() > 0){

                    $errores[] =  $item['correo'] ;

                }
                if(User::where('id',$item['documento'])->count() > 0){

                    $errores[] =  "documento: ". $item['documento'] ;
                }
                if(User::where('legajo',$item['legajo'])->count() > 0){

                    $errores[] = "legajo: ". $item['legajo'] ;
                }
                $error = [
                    'msj' => $errores
                ];

                if(count($errores)>0){
                    $errores_lista[] = $error;
                }

             }
             if (!isset($item['rol'])) {
                return response()->json(['err'=>'La columna rol no se encuentra en el Excel'],500);
            }
            if ($item['rol']=='empleador' OR $item['rol']=='Empleador'OR $item['rol']=='empleado' OR $item['rol']=='Empleado') {
                Excel::queueImport($import, request()->file('file'));
                $data = [
                   'usuarios' => $errores_lista,
                   'errores' =>  count($errores_lista),
                   'subidos' => count($array[0]) - count($errores_lista),
                   'total' => count($array[0]),
                ];
                 foreach($array[0] as $item){
                    if(User::where('email',$item['correo'])->count() > 0){
                        $user = User::where('email',$item['correo'])->first();
                        // ClaveController::clavesMasivas($user->id);
                        $codigo = bin2hex(random_bytes(30));
                        $nombre = $user -> name . ' '. $user -> last_name;

                        CodigoRecuperacion::create([

                           'id_user' => $user-> id,
                           'codigo' => Hash::make($codigo)

                       ]);
                        $user -> notify(new MailBienvenida($nombre, $codigo));
                    }
                    if ($user-> id!= 'null') {
                         AuditoriaController::crear( $request-> idUsuarioCreador,'usuario',$user-> id,'Alta Masiva');
                    }
                 }

                return response()->json(['msj'=> $data] ,201);
            }else {
               return response()->json(['err'=>'El rol seleccionado no esta disponible'],500);
            }
```

Como veran el codigo se encuentra de esta manera cualquiera ayuda seria bienvenida.

Comment: Cuantos registros estás intentando subir? Has intentado poner `set_time_limit(0)` al inicio del script?

Comment: @Pipe son muchisimos registros la verdad hablamos de 20 mil en adelante. todavia no logro saber cual es el maximo que me demora todo le proceso por eso no le pongo un limite aun. gracias

Comment: Pero no necesitas tener un limite... si pones 0 significa que no quieres tener limite... y no importa si se demora 1 minutos o 5 minutos... el proceso no se detiene abrutamente.

Comment: Y tambien debes revisar si el problema que tienes es que la respuesta no se recibe bien en el frontend (porque a veces segun el framework que uses hay tambien cierto tiempo limite), o realmente es PHP el que cancela el script y retorna error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto tal vez no se una respuesta completa, pero si algunas correcciones/sugerencias.

Vamos por partes:

```
public function import(Request $request){
    $headings = (new HeadingRowImport)->toArray(request()->file('file'));
    $import = new CMusuariosImport($headings[0][0]);
    $array = ( $import )->toArray(request()->file('file'));
    $errores_lista = array();
    ...
}
```

Tenés definido `Request $request` como parámetro, con lo cual probablemente quieras usar esa variable y no `request()`. Por otro lado, `array()` lo podes reemplazar por `[]`;

```
public function import(Request $request) {
    $headings = (new HeadingRowImport)->toArray($request->file('file'));
    $import = new CMusuariosImport($headings[0][0]);
    $array = ($import)->toArray($request->file('file'));
    $errores_lista = [];
    ...
}
```

A continuación recorres un array (entiendo que con datos de usuarios), y chequeas si existen registros en la base de datos con algunos de esos datos para armar un array de "errores".

```
foreach($array[0] as $item){

    $errores = array();

    if(User::where('email',$item['correo'])->count() > 0){

        $errores[] =  $item['correo'] ;

    }
    if(User::where('id',$item['documento'])->count() > 0){

        $errores[] =  "documento: ". $item['documento'] ;
    }
    if(User::where('legajo',$item['legajo'])->count() > 0){

        $errores[] = "legajo: ". $item['legajo'] ;
    }
    $error = [
    'msj' => $errores
    ];

    if(count($errores)>0){
        $errores_lista[] = $error;
    }

}
```

Estás *contando* cuantos registros hay en cada caso, pero en realidad solo te importa si *existe* alguno. Cambiar el `count()` por un `exists()` tal vez agilice un poco la consulta.

```
foreach($array[0] as $item) {
    $errores = [];

    if (User::where('email', $item['correo'])->exists()) {
        $errores[] = $item['correo'];
    }

    if (User::where('id', $item['documento'])->exists()) {
        $errores[] = 'documento: ' . $item['documento'];
    }

    if (User::where('legajo', $item['legajo'])->exists()) {
        $errores[] = 'legajo: ' . $item['legajo'];
    }

    $error = [
        'msj' => $errores
    ];

    // Si count devuelve 0 se evalúa como falso, así que no hace falta preguntar si es mayor a 0
    if (count($errores)) {
        $errores_lista[] = $error;
    }
}
```

Ahora, es realmente necesario saber exactamente cual de los 3 datos (correo, documento, legajo) es el que genera el "error"? Porque estás haciendo 3 consultas (una por cada dato), cuando podrías hacer una sola y ver si existe algún usuario con alguno de esos datos. Obviamente no sabrías cual produjo la coincidencia, pero optimizarías aún más el código.

```
foreach($array[0] as $item) {
    $exists = User::where('email', $item['correo'])
        ->orWhere('id', $item['documento'])
        ->orWhere('legajo', $item['legajo'])
        ->exists();

    if ($exists) {
        // Ya existe un usuario con alguno de esos datos, tendrías que ver que mostrar como error
    }
}
```

De esa forma pasas de tener 3 consultas por usuario a 1. Pero podrías ir un paso más y hacer una única consulta:

```
$correos = array_column($array, 'correo');
$documentos = array_column($array, 'documento');
$legajos = array_column($array, 'legajo');

$exists = User::whereIn('email', $correos)
    ->orWhereIn('id', $documentos)
    ->orWhereIn('legajo', $legajos)
    ->exists();

if ($exists) {
    // Algún usuario está repetido
}
```

Obviamente tendrías que cambiar otras cosas más adelante, solo te muestro alternativas para reducir la cantidad de consultas.

De acá en adelante haces algunos chequeos sobre la variable `$item`, pero lo hacés fuera del `foreach`, con lo cual estás trabajando sobre el último `$item` creado al salir del loop. Ojo con eso.

```
if ($item['rol'] == 'empleador' OR $item['rol'] == 'Empleador' OR $item['rol'] == 'empleado' OR $item['rol'] == 'Empleado') {
    ...
}
```

Un par de cosas: `OR` y `||` [no son lo mismo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.precedence.php), en general vas a querer utilizar el último.
Me parece un poco largo ese `if`, no le veo mucho sentido a chequear la coincidencia con mayúscula y minúscula, además ambas palabras empiezan igual, así que se podría simplificar el chequeo. No se que versión de Laravel estás utilizando, pero te linkeo los helpers:

[Str::startsWith](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-starts-with)
[Str::lower](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-lower)

```
if (\Str::startsWith(\Str::lower($item['rol']), 'empleado') {
    ...
}
```

Luego volvés a recorrer el `$array` y hacés 2 consultas: una para saber si existe un usuario con un email, y si existe después lo traés.

```
if (User::where('email', $item['correo'])->count() > 0) {
    $user = User::where('email', $item['correo'])->first();
    ...
}
```

Fuera de ese `if` tenés un `if ($user->id != 'null')`, pero si el `if` anterior no es verdadero, `$user` no se crea, así que el segundo `if` devolvería un error. Y cuando no devuelve un error, no necesariamente estás chequeando sobre el usuario actual, sino sobre uno anterior, está mal la lógica. Por otro lado, ojo con `!= 'null'` es correcto eso? Estás buscando el string `null`? O debería ser `!= null`?

```
foreach($array[0] as $item) {
    $user = User::where('email', $item['correo'])->first();
    
    // Si no existe el usuario, `first()` devuelve `null`
    if ($user) {
        ...
    }

    // Acá no se si querés hacer un:
    else {
        AuditoriaController::crear(...);
    }
}
```

En fin, son varias cosas que deberías revisar. Después de analizar todo eso vería de hacer lo que dice [@HeytalePazguato](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/515466).

Comment: @Arkaaczina gracias por aceptar la respuesta. Me gustaría saber si te sirvió algo en particular.

Comment: los primeros 3 codigos me sirvieron perfectamente pude reducir bastante el codigo. muchas gracias realmente

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Para crear múltiples elementos con una sola instrucción puedes utilizar el método `insert()` que permite insertar un arreglo de elementos a una base de datos

Supongamos que tienes un arreglo $usuarios donde cada elemento ya cuenta con toda la información para cada columna de tu tabla

Puedes dividir tu arreglo en sub arreglos o trozos de información (En inglés chunk) con `array_chunk()`. Esta función recibe 2 parámetros, el arreglo de donde quieres obtener los sub arreglos y al número de elementos en cada sub arreglo (En mi ejemplo estoy haciendo los sub arreglos de 5000 elementos)

Luego utilizas el método `insert()` del modelo de tu tabla (En el ejemplo "Tabla") y listo insertas muchos elementos al mismo tiempo.

```
$chunks = array_chunk($usuarios, 5000);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    Tabla::insert($chunk);
}
```